# why cant I use const arguments in memcpy?

Tags: c++, c, constants, memcpy

I have a [`struct cVector3d`](http://robot.kaist.ac.kr/haptics/chai3d-2.0.0_Doc/resources/html/structc_vector3d.html) and I am `memcpy`'ing it into a char array like this:

```
void  insert_into_stream(std::ostream& stream,  cVector3d vector)
{
    int length = sizeof(double)*3;
    char insert_buffer[sizeof(double)*3];
    memcpy(insert_buffer, &vector[0], length);
    stream.write(insert_buffer, length);
}
```

If I use `const cVector3d vector` in the parameter list, than I get a "`& requires l-value`" error.

Comment: Show the code that gets the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is in the documentation you linked:

```
double &  operator[] (unsigned int index)
double    operator[] (unsigned int index) const
```

When you use the non-const version you get a l-value reference and you can take its address (which is the address of the referenced `double`). When you use the const-version, you get a temporary and the language forbids you to take its address.

Comment: why would they do that?

Comment: @user494461 can't see any obvious reason for it not to return a const reference instead... so best would be probably to contact them about it.

Comment: To be able to take the address of an object, it must have an address in the first place (ie. it must reside in memory). A temporary object provides no such guarantees so you simply can't take its address. That's just how the language is designed: such apparent limitations exist to enhance portability on wildly different platforms and/or to give more freedom to compiler writers, at the cost of programmer freedom.

Comment: I agree with @Tribse, it *should* return a const reference instead of a temporary. For what it's worth that's what [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) does, so it indeed smells like a design bug in the library you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this here in the documentation:

```
double  operator[] (unsigned int index) const
```

The operator[] returns a temporary if you got a const vector. And you can't take the address of a temporary.