# operator overloading in matrices: how to overload () and = at the same time

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I'm trying to make a class of matrices and try to assign the value at that index like this

```
M(0,3)=3;
```

through Operator overloading.
cant figure out how to overload this operator
should its prototype be like this?

```
void operator()=(int i,int j,int s);//how to overload?

float operator()(int i,int j);//this can be used to get that number form that index.
```

Comment: Why don't oveload `operator[]` instead? `operator()` is reserved for function call.  Do you want to construct a different language with C++ operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `operator()=`. You want your `operator()` to return a reference to the element in your matrix. Then you can assign to the referenced element.

```
float& operator()(int i,int j);
const float& operator()(int i, int j) const;
```

You'll probably also want a `const` overload that returns a const reference.

Comment: The `const` version can probably just return `float`.

Comment: @T.C. I'd just stay with references to keep it consistent since there are still some differences between returning by value and const reference. See [why cant I use const arguments in memcpy?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17669913) where someone got confused by it.