# C++ - overloading [] operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a template class Array:

```
template <class T=int, int SIZE=10>
class Array {
    T TheArray[SIZE];
public:
    void Initialize() {
        for (int idx=0; idx < SIZE; idx++) {
            TheArray[idx] = T();
        }
    }

    T& operator [](int idx) {
        return TheArray[idx];
    }

    T operator [](int idx) const {
        return TheArray[idx];
    }
}
```

I have some questions on operator `[]` overloading (I found this example on net).

I understand that `T& operator [](int idx)` returns a reference to an array value with index `idx` and that `T operator [](int idx) const` returns its value.
However, I am not sure in which case a reference or a value will be returned by using the `[]` operator.

Also, if I change `T operator [](int idx) const` -> `T operator [](int idx)`, the compiler complains. Why is that?
I can understand that the compiler complains because only the return type is different, but why doesn't it complain when `const` is added? This only means that none of the class internals are modified, right?

I tried to debug this small main implementation:

```
int main() {
    int val;
    Array<> intArray;

    intArray.Initialize();
    val = intArray[1];
    printf("%d", intArray[1]);
    intArray[1] = 5;
}
```

And each time `T& operator [](int idx)` is called. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On a side note, prefer proper constructors to functions like `initialize`. C++ gives you a perfect tool for objects initialization, and it's called a constructor.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `operator[]` overload will be selected based on the `const`-qualification of the object you call it on.

```
Array<> intArray;
intArray[1]; //calls T& operator[]

const Array<> constArray;
constArray[1]; //calls T operator[]
```

If you remove the `const` from `T operator[]`, you get an error because the member functions cannot have the same `const`-qualification and parameters as there would be no way to select between them.

Answer (score 14):

First thing, regard `[]` as syntactic sugar for calling `this->operator[]`.

The `const` version will be called if `this` is a `const` pointer, else the non-`const` version will be called.

Moving on, you ought to use `const T& operator [](int idx) const {`, i.e. have the `const` version return a `const` reference. That will save the overhead of taking a deep copy.

Finally, the `const`-ness of a function *is* part of its signature. This allows you to overload based on `const`-ness. Otherwise you couldn't have the two versions of `operator[]`.

Comment: I'd even call returning a temporary instead of const reference a design smell/bug here, as it leads to inconsistencies, i.e: [why cant I use const arguments in memcpy?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17669913/1942027) One should orient itself on the standard library to prevent surprising behaviour and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) returns a const reference.